# MVC3 data validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am quite new on mvc3 and have some basic and ridiculous questions that I couldn't answer myself browsing hundreds of blogs. Most of the blogs and tutorials talk about data validation using annotations for EF4.1 code first, but I created the model first, and from there the database. I haven't use any custom T4. So, the question is, how do I validate that all fields in my model are correct when the using is entering them int the form?  Basically need to understand how to use validate the properties from the model and from the client. This question is more for some experts to guide me where to start with it.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Data annotations that you are reading about with code first should still apply just fine. Using data annotation attributes such as [Required()] will be the route you want to go.

Comment: Where should I put there? As the generated classes by EF will be overwritten every time I change the model, right?

Comment: Ah .... You create a partial class named the same as your main class. Assign a metadataclass attribute that points to a new class with your duplicated properties and attributes. I'll post code shortly when I'm not on my phone keyboard or just checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339(v=vs.91).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Data annotations allow you to tag validation attributes directly to the properties contained within your models. When you then use the properties in your MVC page, they will read in those attributes.

Scott Gu describes how to use data annotations in: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2011/02/23/introducing-data-annotations-extensions.aspx

**Where to add them**
You can approach this in a few different ways. You could create a set of view models which are objects that are built to specifically transfer the data required by a specific view.

Another option is to create a different set of objects for use within the web area and separate them from your database objects.